# Dynamic SFTP Outbound Adapter resolver

Tags: spring-integration

I am working on a requirement where i need to send files to multiple destinations using Spring SFTP adapters. So i would like to create a dynamic SFTP resolver similar to Dynamic FTP example. But it's not working properly. I am getting the following exception.

```
  org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Dispatcher failed to deliver Message; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Failed to obtain pooled item; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to create SFTP Session
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.wrapExceptionIfNecessary(AbstractDispatcher.java:133)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:120)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:147)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:120)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:442)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:392)
    at org.springframework.integration.samples.ftp.DynamicFtpChannelResolver.createNewCustomerChannel(DynamicFtpChannelResolver.java:109)
    at org.springframework.integration.samples.ftp.DynamicFtpChannelResolver.resolve(DynamicFtpChannelResolver.java:91)
    at org.springframework.integration.samples.ftp.DynamicFtpChannelResolverTests.testResolve(DynamicFtpChannelResolverTests.java:36)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Failed to obtain pooled item; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to create SFTP Session
    at org.springframework.integration.util.SimplePool.getItem(SimplePool.java:178)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.session.CachingSessionFactory.getSession(CachingSessionFactory.java:123)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.execute(RemoteFileTemplate.java:408)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.send(RemoteFileTemplate.java:282)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.send(RemoteFileTemplate.java:272)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.send(RemoteFileTemplate.java:264)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.handler.FileTransferringMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(FileTransferringMessageHandler.java:142)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to create SFTP Session
    at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory.getSession(DefaultSftpSessionFactory.java:382)
    at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory.getSession(DefaultSftpSessionFactory.java:55)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.session.CachingSessionFactory$1.createForPool(CachingSessionFactory.java:81)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.session.CachingSessionFactory$1.createForPool(CachingSessionFactory.java:78)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.SimplePool.doGetItem(SimplePool.java:188)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.SimplePool.getItem(SimplePool.java:169)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to connect
    at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.SftpSession.connect(SftpSession.java:272)
    at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory.getSession(DefaultSftpSessionFactory.java:377)
    ... 44 more
Caused by: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: reject HostKey: <HOST>
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.checkHost(Session.java:791)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:342)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:183)
    at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.SftpSession.connect(SftpSession.java:263)
    ... 45 more
```

Comment: Please share some code to demonstrate what you're trying to do and where things are breaking

Comment: I am trying to create Dynamic SFTP similar to Dynamic FTP example from the https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/advanced/dynamic-ftp. When i try to run test it's failing with an exception.

Comment: That exception is something that may be useful to share. Please update your post with the stacktrace

Comment: You need to provide the full stack trace; if you don't see one, try turning on DEBUG logging. Also turn on [DEBUG logging for jsch](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/sftp.html#sftp-jsch-logging) to diagnose SSH problems.

Comment: Gary, I updated post with more detail logging. After this exception if i tried to keep StrictHostKeyChecking=No then i am getting a different exception com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: SSH_MSG_DISCONNECT: 2 Too many authentication failures for user